# How to align horizontally a jQuery UI button to a div?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, firefox

I have the following HTML structure (this structure is important for me):

```html
<div>
    <div class="element">
        <div contenteditable="true" class="inputdiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="element" id="zbtn">OK</div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```css
.inputdiv {
    width: 100px;
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3px 3px 2px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.element {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I create a simple jQuery UI button from a DIV (this is also important):

```js
$('#zbtn').button();
```

The button is normally aligned in Chrome, **but not in Firefox and IE**.

Please see that image:

[image: jQ UI button next to a DIV]

and jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Grigur/SPLLW/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:middle` to `.element`, updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SPLLW/1/